# One-to-one relationship with [ForeignKey("ForeignId")] equivalent by Fluent Api - EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

Let's have two entities:

```
public class Function 
{
    public int Id {get;set;}

    [Required]
    public virtual FunctionConfiguration FunctionConfiguration {get;set;}
}
```

```
public class FunctionConfiguration 
{
    public int Id {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("FunctionId")]
    public virtual Function Function {get;set;}
}
```

And here is my current configuration:

```
builder
    .HasOne(v => v.Function)
    .WithOne(f => f.FunctionConfiguration)
    .IsRequired()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Now I want to **get rid of `[ForeignKey("FunctionId")]` attribute** and update my configuration like this:

```
builder
    .HasOne(v => v.Function)
    .WithOne(f => f.FunctionConfiguration)
    .IsRequired()
    .HasForeignKey("FunctionId")
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

So my entity class will be free of having DB attributes.

#### The problem

When I try to test my schema by creating new migration I get following error:

> You are configuring a relationship between 'FunctionConfiguration' and
> 'Function' but have specified a foreign key on 'FunctionId'. The
> foreign key must be defined on a type that is part of the
> relationship.

What I'm doing wrong? Why can't I just use `"FunctionId"` string in the same way as for `ForeignKey` attribute?

Please **don't answer with "Add `FunctionId` to `FunctionConfiguration` class"** - I don't want to have such property in my class.

Thanks.

Comment: What is not working about the solution you already mentioned?

Comment: @Nannanas Oh, I updated the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because as the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.referencereferencebuilder.hasforeignkey?view=efcore-5.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_Builders_ReferenceReferenceBuilder_HasForeignKey_System_String_System_String___) states the first parameter of this method takes the name of the dependent entity type and not the name of the foreign key you want to produce. So your code should look like this `.HasForeignKey(typeof(FunctionConfiguration), "FunctionId")`.

Comment: Thank you! I can also do it like this: ```.HasForeignKey<FunctionConfiguration>("FunktionId")```.